# Neural network regression evaluation based on target range

Tags: keras, neural-network, deep-learning, regression, metrics

I am currently fitting a neural network to predict a continuous target from 1 to 10. However, the samples are not evenly distributed over the entire data set: samples with target ranging from 1-3 are quite underrepresented (only account for around 5% of the data). However, they are of big interest, since the low range of the target is kind of the *critical* range.

Is there any way to know how my model predicts these low range samples in particular? I know that when doing multiclass classification I can examine the recall to get a taste of how well the model performs on a certain class. For classification use cases I can also set the class weight parameter in Keras to account for class imbalances, but this is obviously not possible for regression.

Until now, I use typical metrics like MAE, MSE, RMSE and get satisfying results. I would however like to know how the model performs on the "critical" samples.

Comment: What is the performance of your test set of data in that range?

Comment: @ChrisTosh MSE=1.225, RMSE=1.107

Comment: I mean why you do not calculate the measurements in that specific critical range and compare it with the performance, in general, to figure out the difference? I would calculate the performance in the whole test set 1-10 then in the test set between 1-3 to figure out if there is a big divergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my point of view, I would compare the test measurements (classification performance, MSE, RMSE) for the whole test step that corresponds to the whole range of values (1-10). Then, of course, I would do it separately to the specific range that you are considering critical (let's say between 1-3) and compare the divergence of the two populations. You can even perform some statistics about the significance of the difference between the two populations (Wilcoxon tests etc.).

Maybe this [link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/statistical-significance-tests-for-comparing-machine-learning-algorithms/) could be useful for your comparisons. Since you can regression you can even compare for `MSE` and `RMSE`.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the most straightforward approach. I thought there were maybe some other metrics more specified for imbalanced regression tasks I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is find identifiers for these critical samples. Often times row indices are used for this. Once you have predicted all of your samples, use those stored indices to find the critical samples in your predictions and run whatever automatic metric over those filtered samples. I hope this answers your question.